# How do i add a delay between printed words in Python

Tags: python

I'm  making a text adventure in python for a school project. To save time and a lot of typing, I've decided to make my entire code a function and then apply this:

```
import time, sys
def textadventure():
  #code goes here
for char in textadventure():
  sys.stdout.write(char)
  time.sleep(0.075)
```

I made this so that every print- or input-function would be printed with a delay of 0.075 seconds in between the words, but it's just printing the lines without delays between words. Is there a way to fix this or do I have to use a different function for this to work?

**EDIT:**
I've tried to make the function equal to variable "K". Now I'm facing another problem. This is my code:

```
import time, sys
from random import randint
a = 3
def SayHello:
  print("Goodmorning, you feel like doing something today.")
  time.sleep(a)
  print("What do you do: ")
  Option = input("Eat, Go back to bed. ")
  while Option != "Eat" or "Go back to bed":
    Option = ("Eat, Go back to bed. ")
  if Option == "Eat":
    time.sleep(a)
    Food = randint(1, 4)
    if int(Food) == 2:
      time.sleep(a)
      print("That food was past its expiration date.")
      print("Now you're sick")
    else:
      time.sleep(a)
      print("Yummy")
  elif Option == "Go back to bed":
    time.sleep(a)
    print("Sweet dreams.")
  else:
    print("That is not an option")
K = SayHello()
for char in str(K):
  sys.stdout.write(char)
  sys.stdout.float()
  time.sleep(0.075)
```

I expected that this would spell all text that is printed in the output to be printed with a delay of 0.075 seconds between the words. But it printed the text normally exept for the word None, which was spelled two letters at a time. Like this:

```
Goodmorning, you feel like doing something today.
What do you do:
Eat, Go back to bed. Eat
Yummy
None
```

Does anyone know why None is put at the end of the output and how I can make the text spelled with delay between the words?

Comment: In order of increasingly outside the scope of a school project, other things you might consider: 1) A webpage with js (or compiling some language to js) and using localstorage/cookies. 2) [curses interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) for command line "GUI" 3) A full website for maximum customization, though there are the standard sysadmin security issues with anything web-facing (sanitizing inputs, subscribing to develop lists for notices of security patches, intrusion detection, etc.).

Comment: Tips for later: [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), like a class for the adventure state/"model" (with state-mutating methods) in its own module, then your UI (a REPL prompt, or event loop) could interpret input as invocations of those mutators. A separate module might have a `.render()` to stdout/curses/etc. Also [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is a good tip for such and all projects. Codereview stackexchange may be a nice resource as well for more open-ended questions.

Comment: @ninjagecko Code Review Stack Exchange wants context, things like `#code goes here` makes this particular question not be a good candidate for CR SE.

Comment: @SimonForsberg: My implication was that the user should review codereview's posting guidelines if they, in the future, have a more open-ended question with more code they've actually done rather than `#code goes here`, unlike this question, which is not a code review question but a less open-ended question.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that the terminal you're running your code in is line buffered. If you want the text to appear immediately, you'll need to [`flush`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush).

```
sys.stdout.write(stuff)
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(0.075)
```